# Problems resetting transform/translate with transit.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using transit.js to apply CSS transforms and translations with JQuery, but seem unable to reset back to a start position for an infinite carousel navigation.

This is my HTML, where each image has a loader over the top:

```
<nav>
    <div class="strategy-icon">
        <div class="icon">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Strategy</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="planner-icon">
        <div class="icon">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Planner</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="finder-icon">
        <div class="icon">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Finder</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="network-icon">
        <div class="icon">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Network</h3>
    </div>
</nav>
```

To set the initial state I just use CSS, so no loader is shown:

```
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    width: 215px;
    left: -215px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

The surrounding `<div>` hides the loader with the overflow setting:

```
.icon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 57.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1.5px solid rgb(0, 30, 65);
    margin-bottom: 1.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then on each change of the active item in the carousel, or by clicking on the navigation I have used many variations of JQuery to make sure the loader is hidden, before it can animate back in:

```
$('nav > div > .icon > .loader').css({
    left: -215
});

$('nav > div:nth-child(' + globalCounter + ') > .icon > .loader').transition({
    left: 0,
    duration: intervalDuration,
    easing: animationStyle
});
```

The reference to `globalCounter` is just an incremental variable that counts along with `setInterval`, and the variable that set `intervalDuration` is an integer set earlier in my script. Similarly, `animationStyle` is a string set as a variable earlier in my script.

Can anyone shed any light on why the JQuery CSS reset still applies the transition effect, rather than reseting instantly, without animation?

Comment: any chance you can make a fiddle ?

Comment: $('nav .loader').css("left", "-215px");

Comment: I have tried your suggestion @Owlvark, but Transit supports that way of writing. In regards to the fiddle, how can I add third party plugin references? Then I will can make you one.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mws92/); adjust as necessary